# Swift NavigationBar gradient different than on view below

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, gradient

I have gradient on naviBar and View below but colours are displayed different. Somebody know why? I don't have extra tints on view.

code for naviBar:

```
func addGradientImageView(withColours: [UIColor] = [.amaranth, .dodgerBlue]) {
    let cgColours = withColours.map { $0.cgColor }
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var updatedFrame = bounds
    updatedFrame.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame
    gradientLayer.colors = cgColours
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
    gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
}
```

code for view:

```
func applyHorizontalGradient(withColours: [UIColor] = [.amaranth, .dodgerBlue]) {
    let cgColours = withColours.map { $0.cgColor }
    let grad = CAGradientLayer()
    grad.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    grad.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    grad.frame = self.bounds
    grad.colors = cgColours
    self.layer.insertSublayer(grad, at: 0)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension UIView {

func applyGradientImage(withColours: [UIColor] = [.amaranth, .dodgerBlue],
                        startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                        endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)) {
    let imageView = ImageView()
    insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)
    imageView.expandToSuperviewSafearea(withoutBottomSafeArea: false)
    imageView.image = gradientImage(withColours: withColours, startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint)
}
}
```